# SQL server SSIS OLEDB source to destination?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

[image]

`OLEDB source` table

```
Name,Age,Seq
Gauraw,30,1
Gauraw,31,1
Kiran,28,3
Kiran,29,3
kiran,28,3
Venkatesh,,4
Venkatesh,28,4
```

I want `OLEDB destination` table like

```
Gauraw,31,1
kiran,28,3
Venkatesh,28,4
```

basically I'm creating backup table from `oledb_source` to `oledb_destination`
and my condition is if `seq` column is repeated I want the last row with that `seq` column like in above table `Kiran,28,3` is last entry with `seq` having value 3.

How can i achieve this result in SSIS data flow task from `oledb source` to `oledb destination`.

Comment: Do you have other columns to work with (an Id, or a timestamp)? You can get at the last record in your sequence by using the ROW_NUMBER window function, but you need to ORDER the result set. Without an Id or a timestamp, you won't get the results you want...

Comment: No i don't have such a `column`.

Comment: Can you add one? An identity column, or a DateTime set to GETDATE() on insert would work fine. Your requirement seems to state that you can have multiple of the same record added to your table, yet at some point, you want to keep only the most recent added record (from each sequence). If you don't have a column to identify the latest added record, then you are relying on the order of the records in your table (heap?) which is definitely not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select OLE DB Source

Change Data access mode to "SQL Command" then paste the query below

```
with x as   (select *,rn=row_number() over (order by name)
            from    source)

select a.*
from    x a , 
        (select name , max(rn) rn
        from x
        group by name) b
where   a.rn = b.rn
```

Now you can move your required column

Answer (score 0):

Since SSIS insert data in batches, you cant decide whats going to happen with one row based on what happened with the previous ones, so my suggestion here is to deal with it on your source query.
I dont know your logic but it looks like you want to group by name and get the max age and sequence. Since age and sequence will never decrease, you can use a MAX function:

```
select Name, max(age) as age, max(seq) as seq
from your_table
group by Name
```